# nvm install nodejs fail due to Checksums do not match

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04, nvm

I trying install nodejs by using nvm on vagrant box **ubuntu/bionic64**  but unfortunately having trouble during installation. The installation command run on my local wsl it just fine, not sure why on vagrant box having issue. Below is my installation command and error from the installation.

```
wget -qO- https://raw.github.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | sh
nvm install 12.18.3
```

```
Downloading and installing node v12.18.3...
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/bin/node-v12.18.3-linux-x64/node-v12.18.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums do not match: '7bedb667857950ad616bc1be0be5d96c7e5ba7e1d99f544df54f1fa7d07b67be' found, 'b79e02e48d0a1ee4cd4ae138de97fda5413542f2a4f441a7d0e189697b8da563' expected.
Checksum check failed!
Removing the broken local cache...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3-linux-x64.tar.xz...
##################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums do not match: 'ed85d09bce5a33233ffad2e905e9cdf85d195b1005d1a3579c86381a86dc8e0d' found, 'b79e02e48d0a1ee4cd4ae138de97fda5413542f2a4f441a7d0e189697b8da563' expected.
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 1 CPU core(s)
Number of CPU core(s) less than or equal to 2, running in single-threaded mode
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3.tar.xz
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums do not match: 'be461dce2b2b5cc22aa3752dadd38513053a2b5b0fc6d608a3e7d520066c51cc' found, '71158026579487422fd13cc2553b34cddb76519098aa6030faab52f88c6e0d0e' expected.
Checksum check failed!
Removing the broken local cache...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3.tar.xz...
##################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums do not match: 'd842d965b6bc5f051c9ca0cbe7b7c93878e9bc042f1e9a731bc84107ceb6cb5b' found, '71158026579487422fd13cc2553b34cddb76519098aa6030faab52f88c6e0d0e' expected.
xz: (stdin): Compressed data is corrupt
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
nvm: install v12.18.3 failed!
```

Comment: I was just searching for pretty much exactly the same problem myself - some version differences but  similar environment - vagrant / ubuntu / windows. Interestingly I don't see the same behaviour (ie it works) when I run the Vagrant box on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

See [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=97903&p=474815#p474815)

Was having similar problem. I followed the instructions to Disable the Windows Hyper-V and now my checksum problem is gone with Vagrant/Virtualbox/NVM installation. Sadly this seems to mess up Docker which I use more, so while this fixes this problem, the cure may be worse.